# iterative Hadoop mapreduce in python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

In my Mac I have a standalone installation of Hadoop 3.3.0

I have 2 Python scripts, mapper.py and reducer.py.

I can successfully run 1 step of map and reduce, correctly writing the output on local hdfs though the command

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file /Users/mauro/hadoop_job/mapper.py -mapper /Users/mauro/hadoop_job/mapper.py -file /Users/mauro/hadoop_job/reducer.py  -reducer /Users/mauro/hadoop_job/reducer.py  -input /input/4300.txt -output /input/output-output
```

The problem is:
How can I iterate the 2 stages until a condition is met?
More specifically, the implementation of kmeans I made to get familiar with Hadoop MapReduce.

I can update centroids once, running 1 map and 1 reduce.
I now need to send the updated version of the centroids back to the mapper and iterate Map-Reduce stages a number of times until a condition is met (namely the intra cluster cumulative distance <than a threshold).
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have to use mapreduce? pyspark can be used instead for kmeans

Comment: Yes, I have already implemented the k-means using PySpark. Nevertheless, I would like to implement it in MapReduce as well to make comparisons and to familiarise with it. The main objective of this exercise is learning.